# How to show inbuilt dataform modeless

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I need to copy-paste contents from worksheet to userform manually while the inbuilt excel form is on.

```
Range("Table1[B]").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
```

is there anyway I can make it modeless?